# Jxl cell alignment

Tags: java, android, excel, alignment, jxl

i want to know how can i set an alignment for cell in jxl library , it's default alignment is bottom and when i set alignment for `WritableCellFormat` it throws me this Exception :

```
jxl.write.biff.JxlWriteException: Attempt to modify a referenced format
```

i set alignment this way :

```
WritableFont tahomaboldpt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TAHOMA, 10,WritableFont.BOLD);
tahomaBold = new WritableCellFormat(tahomaboldpt);
tahomaBold.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
```

this throws me Exception in third line.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a WritableCellFormat object and pass this as an argument, when you want to create or add a cell in spreadsheet with the specified format.

Step 1:
you can read the format from another cell (just like the below code or create a new one on your own) and then create a WritableCellFormat Object[newFormat object in below code]

Step 2:
Add all the formatting you want example background , border, alignment etc as shown in the below code.

```
WritableCellFormat newFormat = null;
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
Cell readCell = sheet.getCell(column, row); //read format from another cell(if you want to copy its existing properties otherwise you can ignore).
WritableCellFormat cellFormatObj = new WritableCellFormat(
                    noBoldFont);
CellFormat readFormat = readCell.getCellFormat() == null ? cellFormatObj
                    : readCell.getCellFormat();
newFormat = new WritableCellFormat(readFormat);
newFormat.setBackground(Colour.WHITE);
newFormat.setBorder(jxl.format.Border.BOTTOM,jxl.format.BorderLineStyle.THIN);
newFormat.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
```

Step 3: 
when you create a new cell(or add a cell with particular format in excel), add the format as a parameter.
newFormat(WritableCellFormat  objecT) will the new format which you want to set.

```
WritableSheet s = workbook.getSheet(0);
 //column, row , where you wan the new format , note newFormat is passed as parameter.
s.addCell(new Label(column, row, request.getRuleId(), copyCellFormat(s, column,
                    newFormat)));
```

Imports required for the above operation.

```
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.format.Alignment;
import jxl.format.CellFormat;
import jxl.format.Colour;
import jxl.format.VerticalAlignment;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
import jxl.write.WritableFont;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
```

Comment: Here is a great tutorial: [***Be the Coder:** How to Align Text Horizontally in Excel Cells*](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/excel/jexcel-api/how-to-align-text-horizontally-in-excel-cells.html).

Answer (score 1):

Attention! As reported in http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/, Alignment Class is Deprecated. So, static access as following:

```
format.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
```

where the class `Alignment` is automatically located in package `jxl.write.Alignment`, but it's not allowed. So, correct way to align text in a cell is using the jxl package `jxl.format.Alignment`. That way we can write:

```
format = new WritableCellFormat(); 
format.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
```

Regards.